# Will MySQL be not free in the next 5 years?

Tags: mysql

I don't understand after MySQL moved to Oracle will that make it not free in the near future?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you're using it for, but MySQL for most intents and purposes (Websites, Web applications, internal IT) is and always will be GPL.  If Oracle tried to kill it, I would gather that it would forked and picked up and maintained immediately by a strong community (and it has already been forked by [Drizzle](http://drizzle.org/), albeit for different reasons).